# Javascript inner function is not working

Tags: javascript

i have the following code is not working. I am not getting both alert box info when page loads and when i put the cursor on the input box which has type="password". Both cases are not working right now. I need to make it work. Any help? Please

HTML

```
<div class="field">
<input name="ctl00$logInBox$UserName" type="text" maxlength="256" id="ctl00_logInBox_UserName" class="userName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" />
<input name="ctl00$logInBox$Password" type="password" maxlength="256" id="ctl00_logInBox_Password" class="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" value="" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            var loginid = document.getElementById('ctl00_logInBox_Password');
            loginid.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            alert(loginid.type);
        }

        (function () {

            var loginFocus = document.getElementById('ctl00_logInBox_Password');
            loginFocus.focus = function () {
                this.type = "password";
                alert(this.type);
            }
        })();

    </script>
```

Comment: Check the console, fix the error.

Comment: @Pedro: I tried 'onfocus' at first, even then also, it not working.

Comment: Open the console in this page and try this it works (function () {

            var loginFocus = document.getElementsByName('comment')[0];
            loginFocus.onfocus = function () {
                this.type = "password";
                alert(this.type);
            }
        })(); But you can't change the type, is a read only attribute

Comment: @PedroFillastre [Is it](http://jsfiddle.net/2097c61c/)? @ Sakthivel, please check the fiddle and notice the timing.

Comment: @pedro: I am getting the error that loginFocus is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You are willing to check type attribute of input.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bYaHd/11/)

Please check it, it may help. Correct me if I have misunderstood your problem.

I have just added:

```
$('.password').focus(function () {
    var loginFocus = document.getElementById('ctl00_logInBox_Password');
    this.type = "password";
    alert(this.type);

});
```

***Update:***

I have now tried it  as below:

```
 onfocus="this.type='password'; alert(this.type);"
```

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYaHd/14/)

[DEMO: Using javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/bYaHd/15/)

Comment: the demo is okay, but, i need this entire in javascript not in jquery, could you please change this to work in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute type , use getAttribute command

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    var set = document.getElementById("ctl00_logInBox_Password").setAttribute("type", "text");
    var get = document.getElementById("ctl00_logInBox_Password").getAttribute('type');
    alert(get);
 }
 </script>
```